# How to create git-compatible patch from svn revision, that contains binary file changes?

Tags: git, svn, diff, patch

I want to apply diff from SVN revision to some directory. But that diff contains changes to binary files (.png images). I'm trying to use git-apply, like this:

```
svn diff --force --git -r 1:2 <remote url> | git apply --binary -p4 -
```

But I get error about `expected /dev/null on line 5`.

What is a correct way to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The real problem is about `svn diff`, since it doesn't generate diff very well.
The solution is as follows:

```
svn diff --no-diff-deleted --show-copies-as-adds --force --diff-cmd /usr/bin/diff -x -au -r 1:2 <remote url> | patch -Np4
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to apply the patch via git? Just run

```
svn diff --force -r 1:2 <remote url> | patch -p4 -i ~/patch.diff
```

And then commit the changes that command caused.